# is there a use case for assigning shared_ptr by reference?

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-ptr

Generally, a shared_ptr's must be assigned by copy semantics to ensure increasing of the use count and to avoid a situation where a reference to a pointer exists, but the memory it tracks has already been deallocated in a different thread.

However, I remember that I once did come across a scenario (in multi-threaded code) where assigning a shared_ptr by reference was acceptable, desirable and safe.  I don't have access to the code anymore and I can't recall the scenario.  Can someone think of when such a use would be safe?

To avoid trivial scenario, I'll stipulate that it was a multi-threaded program and the pointer was used in more than one thread.

Comment: Trivial use case: When you pass a `shared_ptr` by `const` lvalue reference to a function.

Comment: If there are no transfer ownerships, better to pass the object owned by `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Jarod42, Transferring the object owned by the shared_ptr is inherently dangerous.  It's sometimes used as a substitute for weak_ref.  It encourages having a 2nd shared_ptr tracking the same object (and that essentially guarantees double deallocation).

Comment: Passing a reference lets you assign (allocate) the shared pointer owned by the caller in a function without the locking and reference counting involved if you return a shared pointer from a function and assign it to another shared pointer in the caller. That's one use case anyway.

Comment: @John Drouhard, I think that was it.  Please, move your comment to an answer.  I'd like to mark it as answering my question.

Comment: Interesting reading: http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich You mean `weak_ptr` is used as a substitute for a raw pointer?

Comment: @curiousguy 5, no, I mean that raw pointer is sometimes used when a weak ref should be. For example, if you want the object to know the shared ptr which contains it. If you store an instance of shared ptr in the object, you create a circular dependency. If you just use "this" ptr, you don't know which shared ptr owns it.If you store a reference to a shared ptr, the instance of the shared ptr can go away, but (if the ref count hasn't reached 0) a copy of a shared ptr can exist somewhere (so your object would have a ref to a non-existing shared ptr. If you store a copy of a weak ref, you are ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a `shared_ptr` by reference allows you to allocate an object in a function without the locking  and reference counting that happens when you return a `shared_ptr` from a function and assign it to a `shared_ptr` owned by the caller.

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to any object, you can use a reference to a `shared_ptr` any time you know the `shared_ptr` you're referencing will continue to exist for the lifetime of the reference.  This is really no different than any other reference.  The object pointed to by the `shared_ptr` is irrelevant; if a reference is used after the referenced object's lifetime has ended, you're dealing with undefined behavior.  It follows that if the referenced `shared_ptr` still exists, then the object it's managing has at least one `shared_ptr` still referencing it, and therefor will not be deleted.

Comment: I am looking for a scenario of when "you know the shared_ptr you're referencing will continue to exist for the lifetime of the reference". I understand this point conceptually (which is why I asked the question). But what could provide such a guarantee? For the sake of safety, assume that the other thread (which uses the shared_ptr) has code which is maintained by a proverbial psychopathic sadist.